# Library in JCenter cannot be resolved by Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

I have published a library to Bintray and I have been notified that it was correctly linked to JCenter. The library in Bintray can be seen [here](https://bintray.com/truizlop/maven/sectionedrecyclerview/view) and just to be sure, it is correctly visible in JCenter as you can see [here](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/truizlop/sectionedrecyclerview/library/1.0.0/).

I am trying to test it by adding it as a Gradle dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.0.0'
}
```

Which should be correct according to the `maven-metadata.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview</groupId>
  <artifactId>library</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.0</latest>
    <release>1.0.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20150717035732</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

However, when I sync the `build.gradle` it throws the following error:

**Failed to resolve: com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.0.0**

I have checked that I am able to sync any other dependencies in JCenter, but I cannot do it with my own library. The library has not been sent to Maven Central, but I think that shouldn't be a problem since JCenter is the default repository for Android Studio. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run **`gradle assembleDebug`** from the command line, for a project created with the new project wizard and adding your dependency, I get:

```
inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor:
com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:sectionedRecyclerView:1.0.0 Errors: bad module name:
expected='library' found='sectionedRecyclerView'
```

Your [POM](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/truizlop/sectionedrecyclerview/library/1.0.0/#library-1.0.0.pom) has `<artifactId>sectionedRecyclerView</artifactId>`, which does not match where the artifact is uploaded or your `maven-metadata.xml` file.